# Parent id could not be accessed from child controller create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

This is my error: Couldn't find Task without an ID

I have this association:

```
TASK has_many :appointments
appointment belongs_to :task
```

Routes:

```
resources :tasks do
   resources :appointments
end
```

In task show, (Im using a partial btw) I have a link to get to create new appointment page:

```
<%= link_to new_appointment_path(id: task.id) %>
```

In appointments controller:

```
def new
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    @appointment = @task.appointments.new
    # @appointment = Appointment.new
end

def create
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    @appointment = @task.appointments.build(appointment_params)

    if @appointment.save
        redirect_to @task
    else
        render 'new'
    end 
end
```

The problem is this line in create action:

```
@task = Task.find(params[:id])
```

Can anyone help me please?

RAKE OUTPUT
           tasks#index
                        POST     /tasks(.:format)
        tasks#create
               new_task GET      /tasks/new(.:format)
        tasks#new
              edit_task GET      /tasks/:id/edit(.:format)
        tasks#edit
                   task GET      /tasks/:id(.:format)
        tasks#show
                        PATCH    /tasks/:id(.:format)
        tasks#update
                        PUT      /tasks/:id(.:format)
        tasks#update
                        DELETE   /tasks/:id(.:format)
        tasks#destroy
      task_appointments GET      /tasks/:task_id/appointments(.:format)
        appointments#index
                        POST     /tasks/:task_id/appointments(.:format)
        appointments#create
   new_task_appointment GET      /tasks/:task_id/appointments/new(.:format)
        appointments#new
  edit_task_appointment GET      /tasks/:task_id/appointments/:id/edit(.:format
        appointments#edit
       task_appointment GET      /tasks/:task_id/appointments/:id(.:format)
        appointments#show
                        PATCH    /tasks/:task_id/appointments/:id(.:format)
        appointments#update
                        PUT      /tasks/:task_id/appointments/:id(.:format)
        appointments#update
                        DELETE   /tasks/:task_id/appointments/:id(.:format)
        appointments#destroy
                        GET      /tasks(.:format)
        tasks#index
                        POST     /tasks(.:format)
        tasks#create
                        GET      /tasks/new(.:format)
        tasks#new
                        GET      /tasks/:id/edit(.:format)
        tasks#edit
                        GET      /tasks/:id(.:format)
        tasks#show
                        PATCH    /tasks/:id(.:format)
        tasks#update
                        PUT      /tasks/:id(.:format)
        tasks#update
                        DELETE   /tasks/:id(.:format)
        tasks#destroy

routes.rb

```
    root 'static_pages#home'
  # get 'catalogue' => 'catalogue#show'
  get 'about' => 'static_pages#about'
  get 'signup' => 'static_pages#signup'
  get 'registration' => 'users#new'
  get 'login' => 'sessions#new'

  post 'login' => 'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'

  resources :users do
    member do
      get :clients, :workers
    end
  end
  resources :catalogues do
   collection do
    match 'search' => 'catalogues#search', via: [:get, :post], as: :search
  end
end
resources :tasks do
  resources :responses 
end

resources :tasks do
  resources :appointments
end

resources :responses do
  resources :subcomments
end
resources :appointments
resources :subcomments
resources :educations
resources :offered_services
resources :works
resources :worker_steps
resources :client_steps
```

Task conroller:

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController

    before_action :logged_in_user_worker, only: [:new] #worker will not be able to acces tasks/new

    def new
        @task = current_user.task_posts.build
        @task.appointments.build
    end

    def create
        @task = current_user.task_posts.build(task_params)
        if @task.save
            flash[:success] = "Task created!"
            redirect_to @task
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit

        @task = Task.find(params[:id])
        @task.county_id = @task.county.id
        @task.category_id = @task.category.id

    end

    def update
        @task = Task.find(params[:id])

        if @task.update_attributes(task_params)
            flash[:success] = "Task updated"
            redirect_to @task
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def show
        @task = Task.find(params[:id])
        @responses = @task.responses.all
        @current_appointment = @task.appointments.first

        #expiry time is start_at minus 2 hours
        @expiry_time = @current_appointment.start_at - 2.hours
        @current_time = Time.zone.now + 1.hours

        @responses.each do |r|
            if r.is_accepted == true
                @accepted_offer = r
                break
            end
        end

    end

    private
    def task_params
        params.require(:task).permit(:category_id, :subcategory_id, :title, :description, :pay_offer, :is_pay_per_hour, :county_id, :area_id, 
            appointments_attributes: [:id, :start_date, :start_time, :duration] )
    end

    def logged_in_user_worker
        unless current_user.client?
            redirect_to(root_url)
        end
    end

end
```

Comment: how about @task = Task.where(:id => params[:id]) ? It may or may not work, but what i wish to convey is why not use where clause instead of find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `:task_id` (specifies `Task`'s `id`), not `:id` (specifies `Appointment`'s  `id`) :

```
@task = Task.find(params[:task_id])
```

*.erb :*

```
<%= link_to new_task_appointment_path (@task) %>

<%= simple_form_for [@task, @appointment], html: {class: 'form-horizontal'}, wrapper: :horizontal_input_group do |b| %>
```

*routes.rb* :

```
resources :tasks do
  resources :responses, :appointments, :subcomments
end
```

`:appointments` shouldn't have it's own resources.

Comment: This line in create action: ' @task = Task.find(params[:id])'. its complaining that it cant find task without an id, but I set it. My routing seems correct but its giving me this error

Comment: @jumbo_siopao : you should search with `@task = Task.find(params[:task_id])` inside `Appointment` controller.

Comment: This is exactly what I have atm. I did verything you said. But when I get to new page, it result to the same error: Couldn't find Task without an ID

Comment: @jumbo_siopao add your routes in the post (only concerning appointment and task)

Comment: sorry, what do you mean add routes in the post. thanks for replying btw

Comment: @jumbo_siopao : what is the output of `rake routes`?

Comment: sorry, im a newbie, how do you check the output of rake routes?

Comment: @jumbo_siopao: open terminal, `cd` in the project directory, run `rake routes`..And also copy the url (in the browser) when you try `new` / `create` methods.

Comment: @jumbo_siopao : I'm like reaally want to sleep right now (it's nearly 6 AM in my timezone right now), so I'll try to help you tomorrow.

Comment: @jumbo_siopao: search for extra `resources :tasks` , under the nested resources declaration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76266/discussion-between-notulysses-and-jumbo-siopao).

Comment: I updated the edit. I really appreaciate your help. PLease... thank you. Me too. it 3am here right now. Thank you again @notulysses